# Quantity theory of money

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, money-supply, money, quantity-theory-of-money

Suppose the velocity of circulation (V) is constant. Annual growth rate of real GDP is 5%. The money
supply grows by 14% per year. Use the quantity theory of money to calculate the inflation rate.

My solution: 
Given M: 14%, V: Constant, Y: 5%, P: ? 
M * V = P * Y 
14 * V = P * 5 
P = 14/5, am I right?

If not, could you please lead me to the right answer..thanks

Comment: You are not correct.  You seem to have confused levels and changes

Answer (score 2):

M * V = P * Y is not in a form of growth rate, so it needs to be changed into

ΔM + ΔV = ΔP + ΔY
Because V is constant, then

14 + 0 = ΔP + 5

ΔP = 9%

ΔP = Change in price = inflation